# Displaying array of data into the table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to navigate to the table view But my table is not showing any data neither it is showing error, I want to save my data to core data and want to display it to the table view but it is not showing anything.

Here is some code snippet of my application -

On clicking of save button -

```
- (IBAction)saveDataButton:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self manageobjectcontext];
//    NSManagedObject *newemployee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self.employeeDB) {
        [self.employeeDB setValue:self.empName.text forKey:@"name"];
         [self.employeeDB setValue:self.empEmail.text forKey:@"email"];
         [self.employeeDB setValue:self.empDesignation.text forKey:@"designation"];
      //   [self.employeeDB setValue:self.uploadImage.imageView forKey:@"image"];
    }
    else{
        NSManagedObject *newemployee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newemployee setValue:self.empName.text forKey:@"name"];
         [newemployee setValue:self.empEmail.text forKey:@"email"];
         [newemployee setValue:self.empDesignation.text forKey:@"designation"];

    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cant save %@ %@",error,[error localizedDescription]);
    }

    UIViewController *objOfView = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objOfView animated:YES];

    }
```

Here is my second view controller code for displaying data into the table view -

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)manageobjectcontext{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    _delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(persistentContainer)]) {

        context = _delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    }
    return context;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSManagedObjectContext *manageobjectcontext = [self manageobjectcontext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
    self.employeeArray = [[manageobjectcontext executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
    [self.emplyoyeeTableView reloadData];


}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.employeeArray.count;

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *emp = [self.employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emp valueForKey:@"name"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emp valueForKey:@"email"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emp valueForKey:@"designation"]]];
   // [cell.imageView setImage:[emp valueForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the data get save and when you retrieve does it return any data ?

Comment: @Gihan,Ya the data is getting saved in the database

Comment: and your employeeArray has data ?

Comment: @Gihan, How to check it? I am a newbie to ios development

Comment: Just a put a debug point in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check if the employeeArray is empty

Comment: @Gihan,my code is not entering cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: are you implementing UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ?

Comment: @Gihan, Yes , it is showing this error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8ec6399e0'

Comment: Are you initialised self.employeeArray, if it is mutable array initialise it in viewDidAppear, And print self.employeeArray(Use NSLog()).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not implemeting and setting your tableview delegates properly. Try

```
 @interface YourClass ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.employeeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //do this
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
 }
```

Comment: it is showing this error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9bcc626470

Comment: you have to implement that delegate method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return yourRowCountForSection;
}

Comment: Please read on UITableViews - > http://blog.luduscella.com/uitableview/how-to-create-uitableview-programmatically-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

```
`- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.employeeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //do this step
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }`
```